# Rx2 java, Consumer interface does not handle error (socket timeout). App crashes

Tags: rx-java2, consumer

I have the following subscriber for registering an accept from the http service provider, but when the url is malformed, I get an uncatchable exception as shown below, i.e. the try-catch doesn't work. (When the url is valid, no problems).

How do I make this waterproof? I want to receive "onError" but this is not part of the Consumer interface. At the moment, the app crashes on this error event. Perhaps it is better/simpler to use Http directly, instead of RX?

```
try {
            someApi.setStationInfo(stationInfo)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                    .subscribe(new Consumer<StationInfo>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(StationInfo abi) throws Exception {

                                                            System.out.println("TestAppZappPc received accept from endpoint, data: " + abi);
                        }
                    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

THE EXCEPTION:

io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: connect timed out
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
        at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
        at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
        at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:71)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
        at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:213)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
        at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
        at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallObservable.subscribeActual(CallObservable.java:41)
        at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
        at com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
2019-05-14 11:41:44.728 31475-32204/com.hdsl.a.zapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10955)
        at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
        at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
            ... 7 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different ways to handle it.

1. Use the 2-parameter version of `subscribe`: `subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError)`. The 2nd `Consumer` will be called when there's an exception
2. handle it inline:

```
someApi.setStationInfo(stationInfo)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
       .toMaybe()
       .onErrorComplete(any -> true)
       .subscribe(abi ->                                                             
            System.out.println("TestAppZappPc received accept from endpoint, data: "
                 + abi)
       );
```

Comment: the .toMaybe is not available here?